# what ".Module" do in powershell

Tags: powershell

I know that ".Module" would show the dll file assembly information, i.e [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert].Module
[image]

but what's happened when "[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert].Module" get run? any reason why named "Module"? the [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert] is not a powershell module, right?

Thanks for any information provided.

what's the story of ".Module", or similar commands? i.e. ".dll";

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `.Module` in this case stands for `Type.Module`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.module?view=net-8.0. As an example, for a powershell class since they're defined at parse time, you would see "In Memory Module": `class foo { }; [foo].Module`

Comment: Thanks for the info, don't know this before. @KenWhite.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @SantiagoSquarzon, so ".module" is for .net class, any information regarding how ".module" search the dll? in windows powershell, "[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert].Module", would show dll in GAC; in powershell 7, it would show dll under "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Newtonsoft.Json.dll". can I control how powershell search dll location?

Comment: yeah, pwsh 7 doesn't use the GAC as opposed to 5.1. Try this in both: `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ? GlobalAssemblyCache`. this article might be interesting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/global-assembly-cache-apis-obsolete

Comment: thanks @SantiagoSquarzon for the information, it's new to me that powershell 7 doesn't use GAC;  don't know how to mark your comment as answer though...

Comment: I can add an answer in a bit. glad the info was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Module` property stands for [`Type.Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.module?view=net-8.0) and "module" stands for the DLL in this case, as the doc states:

> Gets the module (the DLL) in which the current `Type` is defined.

For a PowerShell Class, since they're defined at parse time, you wouldn't get any path to a DLL, instead you would get `<In Memory Module>`:

```bash
class foo { }; [foo].Module

MDStreamVersion    : 131072
FullyQualifiedName : <In Memory Module>
ModuleVersionId    : 8d5451af-b60f-4012-8709-3b28728a9477
MetadataToken      : 1
ScopeName          : RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule
Name               : <In Memory Module>
Assembly           : PowerShell Class Assembly, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
ModuleHandle       : System.ModuleHandle
CustomAttributes   : {}
```